# I have copied a group in pygame but I don't know what the copy is called

Tags: python, pygame

I have recently been making a guitar hero like game, I am having great success but I have run into a problem. I am trying to spawn multiple notes of the same kind so I don't have to individually make a whole bunch of notes. I have been looking all over the internet for the last couple of days but I am still having problems creating duplicate notes.
Currently I am using trying to copy a group (`notered`) but I don't know what the group that I have copied is called. This is my code:

```
#add sprite to group
notered = pygame.sprite.Group()
notegreen = pygame.sprite.Group()
notered.add(Red)
notegreen.add(Green)
pygame.sprite.Group.update
#duplicate group
notered.copy()
```

As I have said I want to know what the new group is called but if you see any problems let me know or if there is a better way to solve this problem feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the result:

```
notered2 = notered.copy()
```

Keep in mind that this is a shallow copy, so both groups will be pointing to the same sprites. If you move a sprite in one group it will be moved in the other one.